# C# Linq: How to do "FirstOr"?

Tags: c#, linq

There is `First()` which assumes there's an element, and `FirstOrDefault()` which defaults to the type's default. What about `FirstOr(myDefault)` where we want to provide our custom default value?

Comment: Starting from .NET 6, you can specify a default value in `FirstOrDefault`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such method but you can certainly implement your own. To do that, you would call `FirstOrDefault` and then check whether it returns `null` and use your own value instead. You can do that like this:

```cs
var value = list.FirstOrDefault() ?? yourDefault;
```

You can encapsulate that in your own extension method like so:

```cs
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static T FirstOrDefault<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, T defaultValue)
    {
        return source.FirstOrDefault() ?? defaultValue;
    }
}
```

You can obviously do similarly for other overloads.